# Locally convex space which is not Banach.

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

I know that all Banach spaces are (Hausdorff)locally convex spaces. I would like to verify that the converse is not true by giving an example of a space which is locally convex but not Banach. I am looking at the linear space $C([0,1],\left\|\cdot\right\|_1)$ of complex-valued functions defined on the compact interval $[0,1]$, where the norm is given by
$$\left\|f\right\|_1=\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt $$
for any $f\in C[0,1]$. The normed space $C([0,1],\left\|\cdot\right\|_1)$ is known to be not Banach. I don't have any idea if the said space is a locally convex space. Any tips? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Every **normed space** is Hausdorff and locally convex. A Banach space is a complete normed space. If you are looking at normed spaces, to be "non-Banach" is the same as to be incomplete.

Comment: Maybe you can add the definition of local convexity you are trying to verify and add some thoughts (or a proof) why Willie's first sentence is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sasisfied by the [Schawrtz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), which is locally convex but isn't Banach. There is a class of spaces called [Frechet spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_spaces) that are locally convex and not necessarily Banach. Wikipedia has a few examples.